# php extract data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql table with the following rows:

```
id_cont  suma_lun   month           year
--------------------------------------------
FL28     2133       March       2012
FL28     2144       April           2012
FL28     2155       May         2012
FL28     2166       June        2012
```

How can i extract suma_lun, month and year foreach id_cont? so that i get an output like this:

```
ID:           Month:  Monthly Sum:        Year:
----------------------------------------------
FL28          March   2133                 2012
              April   2144                 2012
              May     2155                 2012
              June    2166                 2012
```

This is my current code:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$link);
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id_cont = '$cur'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$a=$row["id_cont"];
$b=$row["suma_lun"];
$c=$row["month"];
$d=$row["year"];

}
```

I echo the data in a table
Thanks!

Comment: well i only managed to get first row to showup :)

Comment: You don't show any code here florin. Go on, edit your question and show what you did so far.

Comment: If its what i think youre doing wrong, then you need to put the mysql_fetch_row(array/object) call in a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Use query

```
SELECT
      id_cont, month, suma_lun, year
FROM
      `your_table`
ORDER BY
id_cont
```

Your output will be

```
id_cont  suma_lun   month           year
--------------------------------------------
FL28     2133       March       2012
FL28     2144       April       2012
FL28     2155       May         2012
FL29     2166       June        2012
FL29     2226       July        2012
FL29     2353       Aug         2012
```

then in PHP you can get desired output

```
<?php

 $id=0;

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($records))
 {
    if($row['id_cont']) !=id)
    {
        echo" $row[id_cont] ";
        id=$row['id_cont'];
    }
     echo "$row[month]";
     echo "$row[suma_lun]";
     echo "$row[year]";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the months, suma_luns and years for each `id_cont`:

Since you didn't give a name for your table, I will be using "cont_table" as the table name:

```
SELECT month as id_cont as ID, month, suma_lun as Monthly_Sum, year FROM cont_table WHERE id_cont = 'FL28';
```

Then you would run this query varying `id_cont = ?` to get the records for the IDs you require.

Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to fetch the results into an associative array using a while loop to get your data using `$result[column]`.

For example, the Month in the first row would be: `$result['month']` in the first iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first recordset is fine. However if you want to get ready-to-display representation straight from DB, try something like this:

```
SELECT
  `id_cont` AS `ID`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`month` SEPARATOR '<br />') AS `Month`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`suma_lun` SEPARATOR '<br />') AS `Monthly Sum`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`year` SEPARATOR '<br />') AS `Year`
FROM
  `your_table`
GROUP BY
  `id_cont`
```